# How to add a single .XML file to built .apk file

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just created a test project in Android Studio.

I am trying to add a single config file to a built .apk file using Android Studio.

How do I do this?  I am new to Gradle !

Comment: OK - It seems I can ONLY add .jar files .... ongoing

Answer (score 0):

OK - ONLY JAR files can be added so I did this using the following in "build.gradle" file :

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['applicationContext.jar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put any file in `[app module]/src/main/resources/`. It will be copied into the apk and you can access it with `getResourceAsStream()`.

If your config is a simple list of values with no custom structures, you could alternatively use Android's resources mechanism. I.e., create `[app module]/src/main/res/my-config.xml` and use `<resources>` as the root element. You can then access the config with `Resources` methods like `getInteger()`, etc.